# Disable or Hidden Button X on Pop Up

Tags: javascript, popup

My pop up after 5 seconds will appear.
I want to Disable or Hidden Button X on Pop Up.
I tried with Script:
But it did not work.
Can you help me ! Thanks you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByClassName('cf-cta-close').style.display = 'none';
 </script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2uRq.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: Check the Return value part [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName#Syntax).

Comment: You need to wait loaded DOM at least. https://flaviocopes.com/dom-ready/ or https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ if it works for you. Or try to extend pop-up JS code and add your code.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName  is going to give you a (pseudo) array of items, so its not directly compatible with setting the style as a one-liner - you should only do that if you select a _single item_ such as with getElementByID() .

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.getElementsByClassName("some-class")` will match all HTML elements with a class attribute of "some class" in a HTML Collection array.

You can access the style attribute of the first element of the array like this `document.getElementsByClassName("some-class")[0].style.display = "none"`.

A better way of doing this would be to give the HTML element an Id attribute instead of a class and then access it directly using `document.getElementById("some-id").style.display = "none"`